# How do custom __init__ functions work in pydantic with inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance, init, pydantic

I'm trying to use inheritance in pydantic with custom __init__ functions. I have parent (fish) and child (shark) classes that both require more in initialization than just setting fields (which in the MWE is represented by an additional print statement). So I need to override their inits.

I tried:

```
class fish(BaseModel):
    name: str
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        print("Fish initialization successful!")
        

class shark(fish):
    color: str
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        super().__init__(name=name)
        self.color=color
        print("Shark initialization successful!")
        
f = fish(name="nemo")
print(f)
s = shark(name="bruce", color="grey")
```

but that throws a validation error:

```
Fish initialization successful!
name='nemo'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[149], line 17
     15 f = fish(name="nemo")
     16 print(f)
---> 17 s = shark(name="bruce", color="grey")

Cell In[149], line 11, in shark.__init__(self, name, color)
     10 def __init__(self, name, color):
---> 11     super().__init__(name=name)
     12     self.color=color
     13     print("Shark initialization successful!")

Cell In[149], line 4, in fish.__init__(self, name)
      3 def __init__(self, name):
----> 4     super().__init__(name=name)
      5     print("Fish initialization successful!")

File ~/Desktop/treeline_wt/1588-yieldmodeling-integration/device-predictions/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydantic/main.py:341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

ValidationError: 1 validation error for shark
color
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

The solution I got from a coworker that works is:

```
class fish(BaseModel):
    name: str
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Fish initialization successful!")
        

class shark(fish):
    color: str
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Shark initialization successful!")
        

# f = fish(name="nemo")
# print(f)
s = shark(name="bruce", color="grey")
```

which, on inspection, only works because the fish `super().__init__` receives the `color` keyword, i.e. changing it to `super().__init__(name=kwargs['name'])` throws the same validation error. This is baffling to me, I don't understand why the fish class needs to know anything about the properties of its child classes. How do I understand this?

Comment: Color is property of shark not fish. And you call fish ctor handing it more args it accepts. Not sure what unclear is here?

Comment: The first thing I tried was mostly for documentation, I understand why that doesn't work. The second part is where it gets weird. Essentially it's not sufficient for fish to just accept name as a parameter in init in order for shark to work. And that doesn't make sense to me. Because as you said color is a property of shark and not fish. On its own fish worked fine just accepting name as a parameter. But to get shark to work as a child class I had to change the fish init signature to accept **kwargs. And that's obviously not a hallmark of extensible structures.

Comment: As a corollary, I don't really understand how super().__init__(name=name) in the fish class works. The super of fish is BaseModel, which presumably doesn't take "name" as an init argument. So there's something subtle going on with how pydantic uses super here.

Comment: (Edited to remove the first trial for clarity)

Comment: Ah, this. Please show `BaseModel`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Fish` needing to know anything about the fields defined on `Shark`. It has everything to do with `BaseModel.__init__` knowing, which fields any given model has, and validating all keyword-arguments against those.

You need to keep in mind that a *lot* is happening "behind the scenes" with any model class **during class creation**, i.e. way before you initialize any specific instance of it. The metaclass is responsible for this.

Essentially, you need to think of the `Shark` definition process like this:

1. The `Shark` class namespace is read.
2. The annotations/attributes are collected (in this case `color: str`).
3. Fields are created from those.
4. The parent class' fields (in this case `name` from `Fish`) are added.
5. All the fields for `Shark` (plus validators and a bunch of other things) are fully constructed. It now has the fields `name` and `color`.

The `BaseModel.__init__` method will always look at **all the fields** defined on the given model and validate the provided keyword arguments against those fields.

When you call `super().__init__(name=name)` from inside `Shark.__init__`, you are basically calling the `Fish.__init__(self, name=name)`, i.e. you are passing the (uninitialized) `Shark` instance `self` as well as the `name` argument to `Fish.__init__`.

Then from inside `Fish.__init__` you are again doing `super().__init__(name=name)`, which means you are calling `BaseModel.__init__(self, name=name)` and again only passing that unfinished `Shark` instance and the keyword-argument `name` to it. (Remember `self` is still that `Shark` object.)

But `BaseModel.__init__` will look at that `Shark` instance it got, see that the `Shark` class has **two** fields (`name` and `color`) defined for it and neither of them is optional/has a default value. It will see that you only provided the `name` keyword-argument, but failed to provide `color`. Therefore it will raise a corresponding `ValidationError`.

The fact that you then manually try to assign `self.color = color` does not matter because that line is never even reached.

That is why you must always pass **all** the field-related keyword-arguments "up the chain" to `BaseModel.__init__`. This is why the code in your second code snippet works without error.

This may seem unintuitive at first, but Pydantic models are not simple data classes. A lot is happening under the hood and this imposes some restrictions, which are unfortunately sometimes left undocumented (as in this case) and only become clear, once you actually dig into the source code.